# Smoke simulation appearing black when previewing

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

When trying to preview a smoke simulation, the color of the smoke turns black while the default color of the smoke is grey and takes too much time to preview a single frame and when changing the color of the smoke it remain black[image]

Comment: what render engine are you using? Are you talking about the preview in the 3D view?

Comment: Please add some additional information to your question. 
Some screenshots or a blendfile for testing will also be very helpful.